# XSLT xsl:copy and xsl:for-each on attributes

Tags: java, xslt, attributes, foreach, copy

I have the following xsl template:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="fix-entity-references">   
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:if test="name() = 'href'"> 
              <xsl:variable name="hrefvar">
                <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
              </xsl:variable>
              <xsl:attribute name="href">
                anything
              </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="fix-entity-references"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

I want to use this template to copy the current node, but only after processing all of it's attributes. The current sample is very simple and could be substituted with a very simple block. The test expression will be a lot more complex the point is that there can N attributes on every element that satisfy the expression. This is why for-each is neccessary. I want to process all of these attributes the same way. I tried to print the "current()" value it always works fine. The problem is with updating the attribute of the original node. Setting the value of the "href" attribute to "anything" will not work, because I guess by the time I call it, it is inside a for-each block which means the current node is the attribute itself.

How should I set the attribute of the original block from inside the for-each block, so that the copied node will use the modified attributes?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than `for-each` and `if`, you might consider using templates that match the attributes you want to treat differently, e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="fix-entity-references">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="fix-entity-references"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@href | @foo | @bar" mode="fix-entity-references">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select=".."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

In the XPath data model attribute nodes are not considered children of the element, but the parent of an attribute node *is* the element that the attribute belongs to (i.e. when the context node is an attribute, `..` is the element on which the attribute can be found).  Thus this sample would replace the value of any `href`, `foo` or `bar` attribute with the text content of the attribute's containing element, i.e.

```
<a href="#">http://example.com</a>
```

would become

```
<a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a>
```